# AWS Lambda - Facebook , Yotpo accessToken issue

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to get "accessToken" from "facebook" graph URL and "yotpo" URL using nodejs axios and AWS - Lambda service. I have already done configuration at "facebook" and "yotpo" developer site. Still , I can't get accessToken in console.log and nothing is printed in catch block. M I missing some configuration from AWS-Lambda side. Please suggest.

No accessToken printed in console.log and nothing is printed in catch block

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.